# Apache ( 2.4.58) compiling fails after Openssl upgrade to 3.2.1. on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: apache-2.4, openssl, amazon-linux-2

Apache  ( 2.4.58) compiling fails after Openssl upgrade  to 3.2.1. on Amazon Linux 2, Could you please help me on this.

Error:

```
/var/tmp/httpd-2.4.58/support/ab.c:2319: undefined reference to `TLS_client_method'
/var/tmp/httpd-2.4.58/support/ab.c:2572: undefined reference to `TLS_client_method'
/var/tmp/httpd-2.4.58/support/ab.c:2650: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
/var/tmp/httpd-2.4.58/support/ab.c:2651: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
/var/tmp/httpd-2.4.58/support/ab.c:2660: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_options'
/var/tmp/httpd-2.4.58/support/ab.c:2674: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_ciphersuites'
ab.o: In function `test':
/var/tmp/httpd-2.4.58/support/ab.c:2003: undefined reference to `SSL_in_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [ab] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/var/tmp/httpd-2.4.58/support'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/var/tmp/httpd-2.4.58/support'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: Do you really need to install from source? You have compiled version from your provider.

Comment: Additionally to the option to verify if you actually _need_ this build yourself you might want to head over to stackoverflow for potential helpful information on a problem showing a similiar error message.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593284/undefined-reference-to-ssl-library-init-and-ssl-load-error-strings